# proceed sql statement from Table

Tags: php, sql

I have written a smal content system inside my app.
This render some text and charts based on data in a table.
I also put the sql statements inside this table. 
At runtime the render claas take the formating information and also sql statement from tab and render it in the page. Works nice so far.

To keep it lexible I need also to take some php variablebes into the sql statement.
This normaly is done be concationation like shown here:

```
select * from table1 where userid = ".$actual_user." and ... 
select * from table1 where userid = '.$actual_user.' and ... 
select * from table1 where userid = $actual_user and ...
```

But this do not work when I load the sql statement from mysql table, since php think all is text and php do not recognice to replace the variable with the real value at runtime.
I hope it is understandable what I mean. (eng. is not my native lang)

Long story short, what can I do, that php is replacing the injected variables at runtime within an sql statement which was loaded from mysql table.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are they always the same variables, or are you trying to dynamically inject any variable that is available in the scope?

Comment: it is an set of probaly 10-20. I'm not final yet.

Comment: to clarify, within different statements mayby 2-5 vars each,  overall 10-20:)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is how variables are added to a sql query.

```
 $sql="select * from table1 where userid = ".$actual_user." and ...
```

OR

```
 $sql='select * from table1 where userid = '.$actual_user.' and ...
```

Please note that symbol you start with must end with (i.e. ' or " ) , then "." for adding then the variable.

Answer (score 0):

if I do

> $sql5 = "select * from table1 where userid = ".$actual_user

this will work with no poblems. But if I put the same sql statement into an table and load it at runtime (ew_ExecuteScalar proceed sql script and give the content of kpi_show_sql1 back (which is actualy exactly our sql statement select * from table1 where userid = ".$actual_user))like this:

> $sql5 = ew_ExecuteScalar('SELECT kpi_show_sql1 FROM kpi_template WHERE
>   kpi_id='.$row_id)

Than it will not work. For me it looks like php do not know that within the text is an variabele which php needs to proceed (and fill at runtime with real value).

So my question is more how I can load an sql statement with variabeles from an table and proceed it in a way that php recognice and proceed the variables into.